# Algorithm to prepare array data to another structure for rendering defined HTML output with some rules

Tags: php, html

please, long time I am not successful to find solution for this (for me very difficult) problem and I really appreciate any help:

1) I have data in simple array like this, there is no problem:

```
$data = array(
    array('id => 1', 'name' => 'Some name 1'),
    array('id => 2', 'name' => 'Some name 2'),
    array('id => 3', 'name' => 'Some name 3'),
    ...
);
```

2) But I have to render above showed data into HTML structure theoretically very similar to tree structure in which each parent have max 4 leaves and each node could became parent for next 4 childs (without any limits for tree depth).

a) So in case I have only 4 items in array, on the website is rendered this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
</div>
```

b) In case 5 items it should be rendered like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 5</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

c) In case 6 items it should be rendered like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
    <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 5</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 6</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

d) In case 16 items it should be rendered like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 5</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 6</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 7</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 8</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 9</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 10</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 11</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 12</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 13</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 14</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 15</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 16</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

e) In case 21 items it should be rendered like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 5</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 6</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 7</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 8</a></div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 9</a></div>
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 10</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 11</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 12</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 13</a></div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 14</a></div>
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 15</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 16</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 17</a></div>
        <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 18</a></div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 19</a></div>
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 20</a></div>
            <div class="group"><a href="#">Item 21</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above showed examples are designed for fullbackground screen divided into 4 main equal areas, and these 4 areas could contain also maximum 4 areas inside, and each of these area could contains also next 4 areas etc etc.

In case total summary count of items modulo 4 is 0 than on the website will be same width and height areas, but otherwise there are some areas bigger and some separated into more childs and for that purpose above described HTML code works fine (on static page it is tested well).

So I have big problem to find how convert simple array data into some structure good to process by any recursive function or something else to render desired results.

But as I wrote, I am not successful mainly because each new child containers should be create from last of structure to start and uniformly for each of main 4 quadrants.

I am here to be helpful in answering your questions, if you will be so nice to help me:)

I know it is little bit complicated to describe it clear enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a little trickier than I expected, because of the way you wanted to distribute your items.  But this should do the trick.

The function `arrangeGroups()` will create a nested array like you describe.  You should have no problem creating a function that renders this data as nested divs.

I added some setup code to dynamically generate as many array entries as you want.  Makes testing easier.

```
define('GROUP_SIZE', 4);

$things = array();

for($idx=1; $idx<=21; $idx++)
    $things[] = array( 'id'=>$idx, 'name'=>"Some name $idx" );

$groups = arrangeGroups($things);
print_r($groups);

function arrangeGroups($items) {
    $tempGroups = array();
    $itemCount = count($items); // we use this a lot.

    // The hardest part here is figuring out how many items go into each group.
    // Build an array of how big each subgroup should be.
    // Put all the remainder items at the end of the array.
    // Six items divided into four groups will yield the array
    // (1, 1, 2, 2)
    $groupings = array_fill(0, GROUP_SIZE, intval($itemCount/GROUP_SIZE));
    $remainder = $itemCount % GROUP_SIZE ;
    for ($idx=$remainder; $idx>0; $idx--)
        $groupings[GROUP_SIZE-$idx]++;

    // now we just create slices of the array we were given, using $groupings as our guide
    $offset = $idx = 0;
    do {
        $sliceSize = $groupings[$idx];

        if ( $sliceSize == 1 )
            $tempGroups[] = $items[$offset];
        else if ( $sliceSize > 1 )
            $tempGroups[] = arrangeGroups( array_slice($items, $offset, $sliceSize) );

        $offset += $sliceSize;
        $idx++;
    } while ($idx < GROUP_SIZE);

    return $tempGroups;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help. I've tested your code and it seems to work briliant:) Thx a lot...